# "Delayed Write Failed" when saving to a mapped WebDAV folder in Windows 10

Tags: windows, ubuntu, network-shares, webdav, davfs2

**Problem**

When saving to an existing file in the shared folder, the following error prompt is displayed every time.

> Delayed Write Failed
>
> Windows was unable to save all the data for the file `\<server-url>\DavWWWRoot\hello_world.txt`. The data has been lost. This error may be caused by a failure of your computer hardware or network connection. Please try to save this file elsewhere

The error indicates that a network fault may be the cause, but I can create, read, and delete files fine.

---

**Goal**

A WAN accessible mapped network drive in Windows 10

*WebDAV seems to fulfill this goal, but I am open to alternatives.*

---

**Current Status**

- Server with Kubuntu 19.x, running Apache's `dav_fs` module to serve the filesystem.
- Client machine running Windows 10.
- The shared file system is visible in WebDAV clients, and was able to be mapped as a drive in the client.
- Create, Read, and Delete are functional. Update is not.
- Both client and server are personal computers which I have full access to.
- Both computers are currently on a (wired) LAN connection

---

**Additional Info**

- When connecting to the share via a client like BitKinex, I was also not able to overwrite the contents of a file, but no error was given.
- Windows still shows the updated content when I close and re-open the text document in notepad
- The shared folder on the server is at `/var/www/share`. It is owned by the `www-data` group that Apache runs under. I'm not well versed with file and folder permissions though, so I might have made a mistake

  - The output of `ls -l /var/www/...` for the share folder and it's contents is
  - `/var/www/share/`: `drwxrwsr-x+ 3 www-data www-data 4096 Sep 5 08:22 share`
  - `/var/www/share/hello-world.txt`: `-rw-rw-r--+ 1 www-data www-data 0 Sep 5 08:21 hello-world.txt`

If you have any suggestions or alternatives (i.e. a method of mapping SFTP shares as a network drives), I'd like to hear them.